# Ruby on Rails mime type for mobile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile

I'm trying to detect mobile devices with Rails. I'm getting this error : `uninitialized constant Mime::MOBILE` when I try to access the index page.

mime_types.rb :

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery

private

  def mobile_device?
    if request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
      request.format = :mobile
      return true
    end
  end
  helper_method :mobile_device?
end
```

I also created a index.mobile.erb file so the user could be redirected to this format.

Comment: I could not reproduce the error on Rails 3.2. Which version are you using?

Comment: I updated to Rails 3.2.0. I also updated some of my gems. It now works  as it should. Thanks a lot! Do you have an idea of what caused the error?

Comment: Nope, sadly I don't. I don't see anything regarding mime types in the release notes. Might just have been an outstanding bug that got fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure the rails server was launched before the alias added to `mime_types.rb`. Usualy one is used to see immediately the changes on development enviroment, but in this case, the change was on initializer process.